# How can I escape filenames in ruby (osx) for open/read/hexdigest?

Tags: ruby, macos, escaping, filenames

I'm trying to catalog a bunch of files on OSX using ruby, essentially doing this:

```
hash = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(File.open(fullpath).read)
```

This is failing on filenames that contain apostrophes, which are legal characters for a filename.

The File.open works, but I get an "Errno::EINVAL: Invalid argument" error from the read. The filenames are coming directly out of a Dir[] glob.

I've tried escaping them with backslashes, but that doesn't seem to work.

What's the right way to escape these filenames?

Comment: Works for me on OSX with ruby 1.8.7. Can you post a complete script that fails and provide a sample file name?

Comment: Hmm... you're right. It does work fine with the system ruby 1.8.7, but not with 1.9.2 installed via rvm. I'll have to try an rvm 1.8.7 and see if this is a problem with the rvm version or ruby 1.9.2.

Comment: Mine was rvm ruby 1.8.7, not the system ruby. But I just tried with rvm ruby 1.9.2p290 and it works as well.

Comment: I have ruby-1.9.2-p180, so maybe that's just a bug that was fixed. I'll update that and see if it helps.